# Sticky footer with three column layout, header and horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

What I want is sticky footer with `100% width` (or footer that stretches horizontally along with opened website), and I want to set a color for it. But when I scroll page I don't want the footer to be stuck at the bottom, I want it to scroll away with page when I scroll it.

Then above the footer I want a 3 (right, left and center-content) column **centered** layout that has a header and also horizontal navigation bar area. Then outside this layout I could set background a color and also background image that is attached to top.

Is this possible at all? I followed Ryans Faits method but wasn't sure exactly how to put this all together.

Can anyone help me with css and html code? I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you have something you've tried already, you need to post it. As it is, it seems as if you're asking someone to do it for you. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm